# Is $\lim\mathbb{E}[X_n] \neq \mathbb{E}[\lim X_n]$ here?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $\Omega = (0,1]$ with the Borel sigma algebra and the Lebesgue measure dx.
Let,

$$X_n(w) =
\begin{cases}
n, &  \text{for $ 0< w \le \frac {1}{n}$ } \\
0, & \text{otherwise } \\
\end{cases}$$

Can I claim that $\lim\mathbb{E}[X_n]= \mathbb{E}[\lim X_n]$? I do not think so, indeed: $X_n$ converges almost surely to 0, so that $\mathbb{E}[\lim X_n]=0$. While, $\lim\mathbb{E}[X_n]= \lim(n \frac1n))=1$.

However I may apply the Fatou's lemma and claim that $0= \mathbb{E}[\lim \inf X_n]\le  \lim \inf E[X_n]=1$.
Am I right?

Comment: You are correct.